# Why does a loop over key and value lists add the entire list of values?

Tags: python

I have two lists, one with keys, the other with values:

`keys = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']` and `values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`.

When I iterate over a zip of the two lists, I get the result I expect:

```
for k, v in zip(keys, values):
    print(k, v)

1 1
2 2
3 3
4 4
5 5
6 6
```

However, I have a dictionary, `store = dict.fromkeys(keys, [])` and I want to go through the lists to append the values to the corresponding list.

```
for k, v in zip(keys, values):
    store[k].append(v)
```

I would expect this to give me the following dictionary:

```
{'1': [1],
 '2': [2],
 '3': [3],
 '4': [4],
 '5': [5],
 '6': [6]}
```

but what it actually returns is:

```
{'1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
 '2': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
 '3': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
 '4': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
 '5': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
 '6': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]}
```

It feels like I'm missing something obvious here, but I can't see what it is.

Comment: You make one list (let's call it Harvey), and pass it to `dict.fromkeys`. It then associates six keys with Harvey. As you add `1` to `store['1']`, you add `1` to Harvey. Then because `store['2']` is _also_ Harvey, Harvey gets `2`, then `3` etc. You end up with Harvey having six elements, and dict having six keys that all point to Harvey.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille Thanks! That's exactly what I was looking for, just couldn't find the correct thing to search for.

Answer (score 1):

Using `dict.fromkeys(keys, [])` makes all values reference to the same list, which is way appending to one of them is modifying all of the rest as well, why not use a dict-comprehension instead:

```
store = {k: [v] for k, v in zip(keys, values)}

print(store)
```

Output:

```
{'1': [1], '2': [2], '3': [3], '4': [4], '5': [5], '6': [6]}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me because in my actual code, I'm dynamically adding to the lists in every step of an additional for loop. Thierry's comment provides a link to a solution.

Comment: @evanr70 In this case you should close this as a duplicate.